# Lebesgue Space Definition

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I got a question concerning the definition of the $L^p$-spaces.

Is it true that $L^p[0,2π[=L^p[0,2π]$?

Comment: It's not true, albeit there's probably some kind of isomorphism between them.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same set. One is made up by (equivalence classes of) functions with domain $[0,2\pi]$ and the other of functions with domain $[0,2\pi[$. Their elements are different (remember that a function is a triple: domain, codomain, and subset of their cartesian product), and thus they are different sets.
However, they are 'morally' the same vector space: the function $\Psi: L^{p}[0,2\pi] \to L^{p}[0,2\pi[$ that takes $[f]$ to $[f \vert_{[0, 2\pi[}]$ is a linear isomorphism. Surjectivity follows since one can simply extend a function in the codomain to a function in the domain by adding the value $0$ (or any value, really) in $2\pi$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation! But is it at least true that $L^p[0,2\pi[\subset L^p[0,2\pi]$? @Simone Ramello

Comment: @matzzzz You are missing the point. The domain of the functions is different.

Comment: No, it's not true. For a simpler example of why this is not true, consider the set of functions $[0,1[ \to \mathbb{R}$ and the set of functions $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$. Is it true that the first is a subset of the second? In some sense, yes, but concretely no: the functions have different domains, hence are different objects.